# returning document owner for large list of Google Drive doc IDs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to identify the owner of a long list (almost 1000 items) of documents within Google Drive. The owners may vary between the docs. I have the unique doc ID for each item.

I'm the admin for Google Apps at my domain, and have a utility that lets me punch in a doc ID, and see the ownership of that particular item. However, I have to do this through a web interface, one at a time.

Is there any way to leverage Google's API, say in a spreadsheet, that can return a document's owner when given the doc ID? Or Google scripts perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with a colleague of mine to generate the following Google Apps script that works great.

Usage: With a list of doc ID's in column D, highlight the rows you want to check (any cells are fine, just have something highlighted in the desired rows) and execute using the custom "Automation" menu.

Result: Owner is then returned in column E.

```
function getOwnerFromValue(val){
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(val);
  var user = doc.getOwner();
  return user;
}


function scanRange() {
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var start = range.getRow();
  var stop = range.getLastRow();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("D"+start+":D"+stop)
  var resultRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("E"+start+":E"+stop);
  var result = [];
  range.getValues().forEach(function(obj){
    obj = obj[0];
    if(obj.trim() != "")
      result.push([getOwnerFromValue(obj).getEmail()]);
  });
  resultRange.setValues(result);
}

function onOpen(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Get Owners' User",
    functionName : "scanRange"
  }];
    sheet.addMenu("Automation",entries);
}


function onAdd(e){
  var editted = e.range;
  if(editted.getRow() != 1 && editted.getColumn() == 4) {
    Logger.log(getOwnerFromValue(editted.getValue()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in Apps Script.

## [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

> A file in Google Drive. Files can be accessed or created from [**`DriveApp`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app.html).

Code Sample

```
var files = DriveApp.getId('DOC_ID');
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();

var owner = file.getOwner()

}
```

## [getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getowner)

> Gets the owner of the [**`File`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#).
>
> Return
>
> [**`User`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user.html) — a `User` object representing the owner

Hope this helps.