# getOwner() fails in google drive on folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Basically this is a recursive function that climbs the directory tree of a file until it finds a folder that is not owned by me. the problem is that it doesn't work at all! I've had two different problems, 1, it saying that I do own a folder I do not and 2, returning undefined for other owners.

```
function returnParent(gDrive){
  //check if I own parent
  gDrive = getIdFromUrl(gDrive);
  Logger.log(gDrive);

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(gDrive);
  var folders = file.getParents();
  // Logger.log(parents[0].getName());
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var owner = folder.getOwner(); 
    Logger.log(owner+" "+ folder.getName());  
    if (owner=="DriveUser") {
      Logger.log("Still Me");
      return returnParent(folder.getId())
    }  
    else
      return owner.getName();
  }
```

For the last line I've tried both return owner and return owner.getName();

Comment: What relationship, if any, do you have with the other possible owners? What is an example `gDrive` parameter value? Have you evaluated this seeming duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000942/returning-document-owner-for-large-list-of-google-drive-doc-ids Also, just returning the name of the owner (and not the ID of the file/folder inspected) is not very useful - you don't know which reference is being checked, especially when a folder has multiple parents

Comment: That script is using the same code that I am (file.getOwner). The other owners and I are all on the same corporate accounts. If I look at the folder from Drive, I can see that they own it, yet from here I am getting "Undefined" or the lie that I still own folders that i've passed ownership of.

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment as you replied to it: have you checked that these are not multi-parent items? Why do you return only the name of the owner, and not the associated Drive ID, so you can verify exactly which entity is being referred to?

Comment: I know it is referring to the specific folders because of the logger line with the owner and the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the validation you’re using to check if the owner of the file is you, won’t work because the Owner object will always print “DriveUser” thus the condition will always be true, doesn’t matter who the owner is.  You need to change that condition using the getName() function [1]:

```
owner.getName() == "[Your name]"
```

Or better yet, as names are not necessarily unique,you could use the getEmail function [1] to compare the emails which are unique under the same G suite domain:

```
owner.getEmail() == "[Your email]"
```

Also you need to put a condition to use getFileById() or getFolderById() [2], depending on the ID you’re working on.

Finally, I put another condition to stop the recursive function when the folder you’re working on is the root folder :

```
folder.getName() == "My Drive"
```

Here is the code i tested and worked successfully:

**Code.gs:**

```
//Initiate the recursive function with fileID
function test(){
  returnParent("[fileID]”, "file");
}

//recursive function until different owner or root folder
function returnParent(gDrive, type){
  // Commenting this because is not part of my answer.
  //check if I own parents
  //gDrive = getIdFromUrl(gDrive);
  //Logger.log(gDrive);

  if (type === "file") {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(gDrive);
  }
  else {
      var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(gDrive);
  }

  var folders = file.getParents();

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var owner = folder.getOwner(); 
    Logger.log(owner.getName()+ " " + folder.getName());  
    if (owner.getEmail() == "Your email") { 
      Logger.log("Still Me");
      if ( folder.getName() == "My Drive") {
    // As example it will return this String.
          return "This is the root folder";
      }
      return returnParent(folder.getId(), "folder")
    } else {
       return owner.getName();
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user#getEmail()

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid